# Copy data between single quotes

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have the following list:

```
select 'ABC','A101',1;
select 'PABC\CE','U101',2;
select 'A-BCXY','P01',3;
select 'UABZUE','PU101',4;
select 'WABCPY','IP1',5;
select 'R-YUABC','2U1',6;
select 'PYRABCQWDES','U1',7;
......
......
(900 lines)
```

I want to copy only first data which is in single quotes:

```
'ABC'
'PABC\CE'
'A-BCXY'
'UABZUE'
'WABCPY'
'R-YUABC'
'PYRABCQWDES'
```

I tried with `Ctrl+D` for `select` and cursor key to copy but unable to get complete string.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression. Sublime Text uses the [Boost C++ Library Perl Syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).

Open the find panel and make sure *Regular Expression* is selected and *Whole Word* is NOT selected. Paste the following regex into the panel and click on *Find All*. The first single quoted text following the word 'select' on every line will be selected throughout the document, the single quotes will also be selected.

```
(?<=select )'([^']*)'
```

The components of that regex are:

```
(?<=select )    A lookbehind to find the text: "select "
'               Match a single quote (i.e. the beginning quote)
([^']*)         Match any number of characters that are NOT a single quote
'               Match a single quote (i.e. the ending quote)
```

This variation will do the same thing but without selecting the single quotes.

```
(?<=select ')([^']*)(?=')
```